# How do I transmit video from my iMac wirelessly?

Tags: wifi, video

What would be a good option if I were to transmit any video (DVD, AVI, MOV, just anything) from my iMac to a TV or beamer over the air? 1080p would be nice but is not a requirement. Setup should be simple and the required hardware should be small and have decent design that can be used in a living room.

Answer (score 1):

How about an Apple TV ($99) and Airflick (free), over WiFi?  It'll only be 720p, though.

http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/

There are a number of solutions for transmitting high-definition video:
https://www.google.com/search?q=1080p+wireless

...but to be honest, they cost nearly as much (or more) than an AppleTV, which gets you *way* more functionality.  Unless you have an enormous TV and top-notch content, you're going to be very hard-pressed to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DLNA if your TV supports it and a DLNA server on your iMac to expose the videos you want to stream.

Comment: I know this is old, but [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/download/) (née [XBMC](http://kodi.tv/introducing-kodi-14/)) can expose your videos over DLNA.  I think the DLNA protocol is essentially "broadcast AVIs only", so there is some translation being done on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of [OS X Mountain Lion,](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/) you can now use [an Apple TV](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipod/family/apple_tv) ($99) and [Airplay Mirroring](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#airplay) to mirror your display (in full 1080p) to the Apple TV.

[image: Airplay mirroring with OS X Mountain Lion]

Comment: For Lion, you can use AirParrot.